# why loadash concat instanceof Array is false in google apps script included library

Tags: google-apps-script, lodash

I'm using lodashgs
https://github.com/contributorpw/lodashgs

For some reason, simple statement

```
_.concat([]) instanceof Array
```

is **False**, while

```
_.isArray([])
```

is **True**

In ordinary lodash, it's the same

```js
console.log(_.concat([]) instanceof Array === _.isArray(_.concat([])))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Does anyone know what's the magic happens in GAS for this issue?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your situation, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tested your script, I confirmed the same situation with you. But I confirmed the following 2 patterns.

- When the script of [LodashGS](https://github.com/contributorpw/lodashgs) is used as the library, the same situation with your upper situation can be confirmed.

  - `console.log(_.concat([]) instanceof Array === _.isArray(_.concat([])))` returns `false`.
- When the script of [LodashGS](https://github.com/contributorpw/lodashgs) is used in the same Google Apps Script project by copying the script from the repository, I confirmed that the result is the same with your bottom script ("Show code snippet").

  - `console.log(_.concat([]) instanceof Array === _.isArray(_.concat([])))` returns `true`.

From above results, about the instance, the array retrieved from `_` might be different from `Array` in the client side. I thought that this might be the reason of this issue. But this is my guess. As the test case, I experimented the following sample situation for LodashGS which is used as the library.

#### Test:

1. Create new Google Apps Script project.

   - This is used as the library.
2. Copy and paste the script of [LodashGS](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/contributorpw/lodashgs/master/build/lodashgs.js).

   - And, please put the following script to the top of the script. By this, `Array` can be used from the library.

     ```
       var ar = Array;
     ```
3. Deoloy the Google Apps Script project as the library.
4. Create new another Google Apps Script project.

   - This is used as the client.
5. Install the library as `LodashGS`.
6. Copy and paste the following script for testing.

   ```
    function myFunction() {
      const _ = LodashGS.load();
      console.log(_.concat([]) instanceof Array === _.isArray(_.concat([])));
      console.log(_.concat([]) instanceof LodashGS.ar === _.isArray(_.concat([])));
    }
   ```
7. Run the function of `myFunction`.

#### Result:

By above flow, `console.log(_.concat([]) instanceof Array === _.isArray(_.concat([])))` and `console.log(_.concat([]) instanceof LodashGS.ar === _.isArray(_.concat([])))` show `false` and `true`, respectively.

#### Note:

- As an additional information, when V8 runtime is not used, `console.log(_.concat([]) instanceof Array === _.isArray(_.concat([])))` and `console.log(_.concat([]) instanceof LodashGS.ar === _.isArray(_.concat([])))` return `true` and `true`, respectively. From this situation, it is considered that one of the reasons of above issue is due to V8 runtime.

  - When you use V8 runtime, above workaround can be used.

#### Reference:

- [LodashGS](https://github.com/contributorpw/lodashgs)

Comment: Wow. Indeed, I just moved lodash to external lib sometime ago, and today was wondering why everything "SUDDENLY" broke until I located the thing. Now it makes sense. Cheers!

Comment: @roma Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: @roma As an additional information, when V8 runtime is not used, above `myFunction()` returns `true` for both scripts. So I added this to "Note" section.

Answer (score 0):

Google Documentation says:
Using instanceof in a library on an object that is passed as a parameter in a function from another project can give false negatives. In the V8 runtime, a project and its libraries are run in different execution contexts and hence have different globals and prototype chains.

[Adjust handling of instanceof in libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration#adjust_handling_of_instanceof_in_libraries)